# cannot change background color of custom editText in android

Tags: android

i quoted custom editText because i want to draw lines in edittext 
so i have this class

```
public class LinedEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
private Rect mRect;
private Paint mPaint;
private int COLOR;

public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mRect = new Rect();
    mPaint = new Paint();        
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    SharedPreferences sh= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String co=sh.getString("line_color", String.valueOf(R.color.blue_line));
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(Integer.parseInt(co))); //SET YOUR OWN COLOR HERE
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //int count = getLineCount();

    int height = getHeight();
    int line_height = getLineHeight();
    int count = height / line_height;
    if (getLineCount() > count)
        count = getLineCount();//for long text with scrolling

    Rect r = mRect;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);//first line

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline + 1, r.right, baseline + 1, paint);
        baseline += getLineHeight();//next line
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

and i used this class in xml and in another class (MainActivity) without any problem 
but when i try to change color pro grammatically is not change even if i change that in xml ,is not change

xml :

```
 <my.app.haythamayyash.note.LinedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/detail2"
        android:layout_height="463dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:minHeight="510dp"/>
```

i try that by added  android:background="@color/gray" but no thing changed 
, and i try to change that in java by

```
ed.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

and 
`ed.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);`
but nothing change 
i guess the issue in LinedEditText class because i changed other editText (not LinedEditText) and its work ..
how to change background color of this editText (programmatically) ??

Comment: use ed.setBackgroundResource(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity, R.color.your_color)) ; place your_color in the color.xml             replace android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent" with   android:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"  you could also omit background tint as in this cars it is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in LinedEditText in onDraw() method for changing its color:

```
 canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
```

or by resources layout file you can do this like:

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code that would help u , it help me

```
        app:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
```

Comment: i want programmatically ,but ur right its perfect in xml , thank u